# Spring Data JPA method

Tags: hibernate, jpa, methods, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have method

```
List<Notification> findTop20ByToUserIdAndIdGreaterThanAndOrderByIdDesc(Long ToUserId, Long lastId);
```

I have notification list and with this method I want:

1. Select Notification that send to "toUserId"
2. Select last 20 added
3. Sort that 20 by Desc
4. And Select that one greater than(Number of lastId which I provide to method(for updating reason)).

   that doesn't work and throw exception like that:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'notificationRepo': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.bagenger.persistence.dao.NotificationRepo.findTop20ByToUserIdAndIdGreaterThanAndOrderByIdDesc(java.lang.Long)! No property greaterThanAnd found for type Long! Traversed path: Notification.id.
```

```
 My Entity:

@Entity
@Data
public class Notification {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    private Long fromUserId;
    private Long toUserId;
    private String url;
    
    @ColumnDefault("false")
    private boolean isRead;
    private String message;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime createDate;
}
```

How could I rewrite method for proper work?

Comment: The nested exception says: greaterThanAnd is not an operator. You are making logical and between greaterthan and orderby which is wrong. Remove the 'And'

Comment: This version also doesn't work : 1. findTop20ByToUserIdAndIdGreaterThanIdOrderByIdDesc  2. findTop20ByToUserIdOrderByIdDescAndIdGreaterThan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like problem was in name of method should be added Entity Class Name: Notification
This one is working:

```
List<Notification> findTop20NotificationByToUserIdAndIdGreaterThanOrderByIdDesc(Long ToUserId, Long lastId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Method name is not as per standards. You can try below method name.

```
List<Notification> findTop20NoByToUserIdIsAndIdIsGreaterThanOrderByIdDesc(Long ToUserId, Long lastId);
```